# Cant build after adding com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0 in android

Tags: android, android-support-library

If I add

```
 com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0
```

in my gradle build folder the app produces this error

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':MyAPP:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Any idea on how can I debug this?
Thanks
Here are more details on the gradle console output:

```
:SecretEscapes:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 66146 into a non-jumbo instruction!
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:26)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:72)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:49)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:842)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:813)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:786)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:682)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:542)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: There is more in your Gradle console than just those two lines, including an explanation of what the problem is. Scroll upwards in that console and look for the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've reached 65K methods limit.

Try this:
- add new dependency to your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

- enable multidex in the same build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "yourId"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

- add multidex support in your manifest.xml file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ...
```

for more information see https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Thanks this did the job